# Iteration through lists of different length

Tags: python, loops

I have to use a backwards loop:

```
for i in range(len(my_ls))[::-1]:
    print i
```

But some of the lists have `length = 1` (as in `['one']`).

As a result the interpreter prints nothing at all.

Nevertheless, in python's own shell it works all right and 0 is printed, as was planned.

Any ideas how to overcome this problem?
I run Python 2.6.6 on Debian Squeeze.

Comment: You mean it works in python shell, but doesn't work from a script?

Comment: This is strange. Post the entire sample code, including the test data explicitly

Answer (score 4):

Could you not just pass the list to  [`reversed()`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=reverse#reversed) and then iterate over the resulting reverse iterator?

```
for x in reversed(lst):
    print x
```

Comment: NB `reverse` mutates the list.

Comment: `for i in reversed(my_ls)` gets around that (and is better style, anyway).

Comment: Terribly sorry, guys! I forgot the 'if len(my_ls) > 1', on the same page. Should have gone to bed earlier. :)

Comment: Paul - you should delete this question so you don't confuse future users of the site (and because it's no longer valid)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
>>> li = ['one']
>>> for i in range(len(li)-1, -1, -1):
...    print li[i]
... 
one
```

**EDIT:** The difference between my answer and Acorn's one is that:

- Acorn's method [using `.reverse()`] modifies the list in place
- Using `reversed()` would create an iterator object
- My method doesn't do any of the previous two

Using `.reverse()` or `reversed()` is more idiomatic in python. But the `range` parameters are there to give you this possibility too (memory-wise I'm not sure if my method has any advantage over `reversed()` though!).

HTH!

Comment: Terribly sorry, guys! I forgot the 'if len(my_ls) > 1', on the same page. Should have gone to bed earlier. :)

Comment: @paul_k - Not sure what you mean, but any of the methods I mention in my answer will work regardless of the number of items in the list...

Comment: Sure, it all works now. I used 'reversed()'. I just used this 'if' statement and cut off all 1-item lists. That's why nothing was printed in that case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, all you're going to print out there is the offset of each item from the end of the range, not the items in the list at all.

The range looks like you're trying to write C in Python, to me.

What you want is something like this:

```
>>> l = ['one']
>>> for each in l[-1::-1]:
>>>    print each
...
one
>>> l.append('two')
>>> for each in l[-1::-1]:
>>>    print each
...
two
one
```

The construction `for each in l[-1::-1]` iterates from the end of the list to the start of the list, regardless of list size and without the awkward involvement of `range`.